# Method "SeriesCollection.Add" failing for a correct input passed

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to add a new series/legend in my chart via code using the ***SeriesCollection.Add*** method, but it throws in Type mismatch error as shown. Documentation says the source argument should be of range type but when given a range, it throws in the error at highlighted line. The same error happens in the ***SetSourceData*** method too, which also needs a range input.  [Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.seriescollection.add)

**CODE:**

```
If SetDelShape.HasChart Then
                               
Dim SelChart As PowerPoint.Chart
Set SelChart = SetDelShape.Chart
Dim Selchtdat As PowerPoint.ChartData
Set Selchtdat = SelChart.ChartData
Dim OriSheet As Worksheet
Set OriSheet = Selchtdat.Workbook.Sheets(1)
Dim SelSheet As Worksheet
Set SelSheet = Selchtdat.Workbook.Sheets("TempSheet")
Dim SelSheetlrow As Long
SelSheetlrow = SelSheet.Cells(SelSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim SelSheetlcol As Long
SelSheetlcol = SelSheet.Cells(1, SelSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim OriSheetlrow As Long
OriSheetlrow = OriSheet.Cells(OriSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim SwapRnge1 As Range
Dim TempRange1 As Variant
Set SwapRnge1 = OriSheet.Range("A1:A" & OriSheetlrow)
TempRange1 = SwapRnge1
                                    
Dim SwapRnge2 As Range
Dim TempRange2 As Variant
Set SwapRnge2 = SelSheet.Range("A1:" & NumToLet(SelSheet, SelSheetlcol) & SelSheetlrow)
TempRange2 = SwapRnge2
   
On Error Resume Next
Selchtdat.Activate
On Error GoTo 0
Excel.Application.Visible = True

' Here new line items are populated in a dictionary. Code not included because a bit complex

Dim oIndex, jIndex As Integer
Dim lrowbrand As Long

 For Each Key In dict.keys
    If dict(Key) = "NotPresent" And dict(Key) <> "" Then
       lrowbrand = OriSheet.Cells(OriSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
             For oIndex = 1 To UBound(TempRange2, 1)
                    If LCase(SwapRnge2.Cells(oIndex, 1).Value) = Key Then   
                         SelSheet.Range("A" & oIndex & ":" & NumToLet(SelSheet, SelSheetlcol) & oIndex).Copy
                         OriSheet.Range("A" & (lrowbrand + 1) & ":" & NumToLet(SelSheet, SelSheetlcol) & lrowbrand + 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats) 
                         Dim xRange As Range
                         Set xRange = OriSheet.Range(OriSheet.Cells((lrowbrand + 1), 1), OriSheet.Cells((lrowbrand + 1), SelSheetlcol))
                         SelChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=xRange ', Rowcol:=xlRows
                         Exit For
                     End If
               Next
       End If
 Next

End if
```

Snippet where error occurs:

```
 Dim xRange As Range
 Set xRange = OriSheet.Range(OriSheet.Cells((lrowbrand + 1), 1), _
                             OriSheet.Cells((lrowbrand + 1), SelSheetlcol))

 SelChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=xRange
```

**PICS:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have more code than this, correct? If so, can you share more of it?

Comment: Well, it is quite exhaustive but i will try to include the relevant portions.

Comment: `SelChart` is a `PowerPoint.Chart` object, not the same as `Excel.Chart` (which is the documentation link you were referring to). Based on the documentation for [PowerPoint.Chart.SeriesCollection.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.seriescollection.add) method, seems like it accepts the address of the excel range in string so you could try passing `xRange.Address(External:=True)`. (Note: it says the workbook has to be associated with the chart, I don't use PowerPoint much so I'm not sure what that means) @Charlie

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I will try that out, right away.

Comment: @RaymondWu It worked. Thanks. I didn't quite understand what the argument External is.

Comment: So it work even without External argument? E.g. lets say you want the address of cell A1 jn a worksheet named "Sheet 1", setting `True` to the argument will return something like `[workbook.xlsx]'Sheet 1'!$A$1`, detailing where the cell A1 comes from. (`False` to the argument will return just `$A$1`)

Comment: If you see the sample given in the documentation of `Add` method,you will see the source argument is `Source:="Sheet1!B1:B10`, which makes me think it might need an external reference of the cell address (I could be wrong since I rarely need to deal with external address)

Comment: @RaymondWu Yes it works even without the external argument. Thank you so much. I was stuck on this for a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your documentation is for `Excel.Chart` whereas you are working with `PowerPoint.Chart`.

Based on the documentation of [PowerPoint.Chart.SeriesCollection.Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.seriescollection.add), you only need to pass the address in string so:

```
SelChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=xRange.Address
```